# How to evaluate integrals of type $\int\frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x+ 4\sin^2x}\,dx$

Tags: integration

I think it is by substitution but I don't  have any clue on how to go further. Should I substitute $$\sin^2x=t~?$$

$$\int\frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x+ 4\sin^2x}\,dx$$

Comment: Ok! So I divided by $$cos^2x$$ and then I solved by dividing by 4. Still,I would like to know more methods.

Comment: OK!  So you don't need to start a post with "OK!"!

Comment: What is $cos^2x+sin^2x$?

Comment: Ok! I will keep in mind

Comment: Your query, which I consider to be an **extremely** relevant question in the study of Calculus, begs the question:  Assuming that you have encountered this problem in a class, &/or from a book, what does the book (or your class notes) **read** on which substitution to use?  For some (indefinite) Integration problems, I think that it is reasonable for the student to be expected to *experiment* to find the right substitution to use.  This problem is **not** one of them.  ...see next comment

Comment: This means that before you were *confronted* with this problem, the book/class should have **trained** you on how to attack general problems of this type.  If the training is there, and you simply misplaced your notes, or didn't read the corresponding pages in the book, okay, no big deal.  **However**, if this is not the case, if you were confronted with this problem with inadequate prior training, then you have a very legitimate complaint against your teacher, or the book author.

Comment: You could try tangent half-angle substitution.

Comment: I will try that!

Comment: @KentaS Tangent half-angle substitution would lead to an extremely hazy mess here. Note that the trigonometric expressions in the integrad are squared.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{gather*}
\int \frac{\cos^{2} x}{\cos^{2} x+4\sin^{2} x} dx\\
I=\int \frac{1}{1+4\tan^{2} x} dx\\
Let\ \tan x\ =t\\
\sec^{2} x\ dx=dt\\
dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^{2}}\\
I=\ \int \frac{dt}{\left( 1+t^{2}\right)\left( 1+4t^{2}\right)} =\frac{1}{3}\int \left(\frac{dt}{t^{2} +\frac{1}{4}} -\frac{dt}{t^{2} +1}\right)\\
\end{gather*}
The last expression is attained by using the method of partial fractions, and is solvable by standard integration techniques.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you tell me what is wrong with my answer. Is it different because of constant of integration? Thanks again!

Comment: @NatashaJ You made a mistake during the change of variables. If you substitute $\tan x=t$, you have to substitute back $\sec^{2} xdx=dt$, which is equivalent to $dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^{2}}$. You forgot to do this, hence the resultant error.

Comment: Oh! Ok I got it now. But if you divide by $$cos^2x$$  and then take out 4 common, apply the formula of $$arctan$$, you get a different answer. After solving your answer it matches the one in my text, but why does it not match when we divide 
by  $$cos^2x$$. Is it due to constant of integration?

Comment: @NatashaJ $\int \frac{dx}{1+4\tan^{2} x} \neq \arctan( 2\tan x)$ Does this clear anything?

Comment: Why though, is it not equal?

Comment: @NatashaJ No, the two integrals aren't equal. You can verify that yourself :)

Comment: Ok! Thank you! I will verify and then reply! I did. God, I am so dumb. I was treating tanx as if it was x. Sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the denominator by using $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and then try to express the resultant wholly in terms of $\tan x$. Then substitute $u= \tan x$. Its pretty much just applying standard identities from there onwards.

Answer (score 1):

After dividing by $$cos^2x$$ I got $$\int1/(1+4tan^2x)\,dx$$

And solving it, my answer is $$(arctan(2tanx))/2$$. Is this correct? The answer given in textbook is different. It is
$$(-1/3)arctan(tanx)-(2/3)arctan(2tanx)$$

I graphed my solution and the one in textbook. They are different. Then how to know, which substitution will give me a correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

In general, for the integral of an arbitrary rational function of trigonometric functions, the trick is to use the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) $t=\tan(x/2).$ Then
$$\sin x=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2},\qquad \cos x=\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\qquad \tan x=\dfrac{2t}{1-t^2},\qquad dx=\dfrac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$ transform the original integral to an integral of a rational function, which can solve via partial fractions. The problem that you have posted here has even simpler solution. Note that $$\sin^2x=\dfrac{\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x},\qquad\text{and}\qquad \cos^2x=\dfrac{1}{1+\tan^2x}.$$ Hence $T=\tan x$ would make a perfectly good substation. Then $$\int\frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x+ 4\sin^2x}\,dx=\int\dfrac{1}{(1+4T^2)(1+T^2)}\,dT=\dfrac{1}{3}\int\left(\dfrac{4}{1+4T^2}-\dfrac{1}{1+T^2}\right)\,dT$$

**Added:** This second substitution is secretly again the Weierstrass substitution. This is a consequence of the fact that $$\sin^2x=\dfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos (2x)),\qquad \cos^2x=\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\cos (2x)).$$

Comment: Thank you! Again, you answer is informative!!

Answer (score 1):

Integrate as follows

\begin{align}
\int\frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x+ 4\sin^2x}\,dx
=\frac13 \int\left( -1+ \frac{4}{4-3\cos^2x}\right)dx\\
=-\frac13x +  \frac13\int  \frac{\sec^2x}{\frac14+\tan^2x}dx\\
=-\frac13x +  \frac23 \tan^{-1}(2\tan x)+C
\end{align}